# What does the string passed as selector to the UI Tests framework mean

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

What does the string passed to the square brackets of selectors actually mean?

```
[app.images[@"swipeleft"] swipeLeft]; // The @"swipeleft" here

XCUIElement *element = app.buttons[@"icon share"]; // The @"icon share" here
```

It seems for me that it can represent both visible text of the controls and their names. Am I right? What is the actual behavior of control selecting then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. It can be accessibility label or accessibility  identifier or text on label.

Comment: What is the order then? And what is the full list of the things that can represent this string?